# Google Maps API v3 : drag and drop a marker like the "street view" button

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm still thinking of implementing a button to place a marker like the "street view" one.
I know how to create controls and add them to the map but I can't handle the drag and drop.

Have you ever tried this ?